# How can I redirect from an action creator after a fech using the response as a param?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch-api

I'm working with an API that returns the id of the last insert. On the other hand, I have an action creator on Redux that makes the fetch post request. How can I take the response from the fetch and redirect based on the response?

In my action creator, I have:

```
export const newPostRequest = (userid, title, body, history) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        await fetch('/posts', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'Application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'Application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({post: {user_id: userid, title: title, body: body}})
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        // I want to redirect from here to '/posts/:id' where id comes from the response
    }
}
```

And in my component, I have:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {newPost: (user, title, body) => dispatch(newPostRequest(user, title, body)) }
}


[...]


const handleSubmit = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  await props.newPost(props.state.user.currentUser.userId, state.title, state.body)
  // I know I should redirect from here, but how can I get the response from the fetch?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `// I know I should redirect from here, but how can I get the response from the fetch?`

You can assign the result of an async function and use it like any other assignment.

```js
const handleSubmit = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const newPostResponse = await props.newPost(props.state.user.currentUser.userId, state.title, state.body)
  redirect(newPostResponse.id); // or whatever you need to do to redirect
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with bind, could you explain a bit further?

Comment: Apologies for using that terminology – it's certainly overloaded in Javascript. By "binding" I meant what is also referred to as "variable assignment." You can _assign_ the result of an async function and use it just like any other assignment.